# How to remove legend from Pandas Parallel Coordinates and resize the canvas/image?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-coordinates

I have the classical example in Pandas below, and I want to remove the legend from the image and resize it in 1024 x 300 for instance, how can I do that?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import parallel_coordinates

data = pandas.read_csv('iris.csv', sep=',')

pc=pd.plotting.parallel_coordinates(
    data,'species',
    color=('#556270','#4ECDC4','#C7F464'))
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.gca().legend_.remove()`

Comment: Thank you bigbounty, I already tried something like that but the result is:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-5a85a62bfd50> in <module>
----> 1 plt.gca().legend_.remove()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: For what it's worth: @bigbounty's solution worked for me :)